# Django form validation fails (on update)

Tags: django, forms, validation, duplicates

I'm fighting with the Django form validation for a while now. I'm using pretty basic code. Returning the form data using an ajax request is the only special thing but I don't think its the cause auf my problems here.
I'm trying to update an user entry. I create an instance of the user and I feed that instance into the CreateForm() but I still get the duplicate username error.

here is a part of the view:

```
def user_update(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        print request.POST
        user = User.objects.get(pk=int(request.POST['pk']))
        print user
        form = UserCreateForm(request.POST, instance=user)
        print form
        if form.is_valid():
            form_cleaned = form.cleaned_data
        else:
            print '### form is invalid ###'
            print form.error_messages
```

The output for `request.POST` is:

```
<QueryDict: {u'username': [u'testuser'], u'password1': [u'test'], u'password2': [u'test'], u'pk': [u'27'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'wyBoaBAlxLTO952BzWSxR7HMK6W7nsAM'], u'email': [u'soso@soso.so']}>
```

The output for `print user` is:

```
testuser
```

In `print form` I always get the duplicate username error, hence the form is always invalid.

Please give me a hint. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: IMHO, if the user is already authenticated, setting the `instance=user` would be wrong and I think this is what generates the error.

Comment: If you are trying to update a user, why are you using the `UserCreateForm`? You should use `UserChangeForm` instead.

Comment: @equinoxel: the user (like admin) that tries to change the record of another user. The first one is authenticated but from what I know I need to create an instance of the user that I want to update since Django would try to create that user otherwise.

Comment: @Burhan Khalid: ok using the CreateForm in order to change a user record looks strange. I thought it would be ok since the CreateForm contains all fields that are relevant for the user and hence could be used to update the user as well.

Answer (score 2):

For form validation, you have used `UserCreateForm`.

Apart from the regular regex validation of fields, the `UserCreateForm` also checks if a given username is available or not. And any existing user will fail this check.

You should use an appropriate form like `UserChangeForm` or if your application only updates a particular field like password, then choose from the [built in forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/auth/#module-django.contrib.auth.forms).

Comment: Thanks Sudipta, looks like I underestimated the power of these form functions. All I wanted to do is to update a subset of the user fields (like username, emailaddress, first and last_name) and use the form validation to the check and clean the returned data. If I want to use the UserChangeForm to perform this, do I need to return all the data that the generated forum provides or will it work with an subset?

Comment: You could create a custom user form which inherits from UserChangeForm and then specify only the fields you want to be editable within that

Answer (score 1):

With reference to [`UserCreationForm`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L66) in django, it has `clean_username()` validation method that checks if user with given username already exists, if so raises the validation error that you are getting.

You should better use `UserChangeForm` if you want to update user fields.

Comment: thanks Rohan, please look at my comment to Sudipta answer since you two provided the same answer ...

Comment: @32smooth, changing `username` is non-trivial. its like adding new user, so I don't think its appropriate do change `username` through update. If you want fields that are not part of `UserUpdateForm` you can write the form (inherit from default forms) and use that.

Answer (score 0):

The `UserCreationForm`'s `clean_username()` has the following code:

```
User._default_manager.get(username=username)
```

If this is successful, you get your error. Since your user (`admin`) already exists, you'll always get the error. As suggested by @sudipta, you're better off with the `UserChangeForm`.

IMHO, you could define your own custom form either with your own behaviour rather than using a stock one and deviate from its original purpose.